# Newsletter block doesn't show on homepage

Tags: magento-1.9

My theme have supplied a newsletter theme `/frontend/galio/ma_galio1/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml`

I am using this block on my footer PS: This block is pre-supplied with my theme

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

I don't know why the block doesn't show on my [site](http://www.singhcycle.com)
Here's the footer. Interestingly, I don't see the footer when I turned on template hints. 
/frontend/galio/ma_galio1/template/page/html/footer.phtml

```
<div class="ma-footer-container">
<div class="footer-static-container"> 
    <div class="footer-static-2">
        <div class="container">
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer_static_2')->toHtml() ?>
        </div>

    </div> 
</div>

<div class="footer-static">
    <div class="container">
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer_static')->toHtml() ?>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box-left">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("footer_links") ?>
            <address><?php echo $this->getCopyright() ?></address>
        </div> 
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('payment')->toHtml() ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("store_switcher")?>

    </div>

</div>
<div id="back-top" class="hidden-xs"></div>
```

Comment: Can you post the content of your footer template please ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is permission of static block. 
In admin: go 
System->Permission->blocks
**Add New Blocks**

**Block Name**: newsletter/subscribe

**Is Allowed**: Yes

Save.
Should work.

Comment: Finally was wondering what the hell happened to my newsletter, cheers dude

Comment: my side its not working?